# Should you declare variable before hand in python when using list append and For loop?

Tags: python

After receiving an error in the code below i ended up adding

```
    new_list = [] 
    summation = 0
```

after the second line. But i fail to understand why i had to do that. I thought variables did not have to be declared early on in python

```
    a = int(input())
    b = int(input())
    while a <= b:
    if a % 3 == 0:
        new_list.append(a)
        a += 1
    for number in new_list:
        summation += int(number)
    print(summation / len(new_list))
```

Comment: `new_list.append` wouldn't point to anything if `new_list` was not already defined.  Similarly, `summation += ...` is a shorthand for `summation = summation + ...` and thus it will need `summation` to exist beforehand.

Comment: Variables must exist before you access them, yes.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  There are no variable declarations in Python.  In almost any language, a variable must be defined before its first reference.

Answer (score 4):

In general, Python does not require variables to be declared (except for a couple of cases). In this case, you are not declaring a variable but rather initializing it. Let's imagine that variables are boxes. In python, you don't have to say, please make a box and call it x. The issue is when you come across `summation += int(number)`. This tells python, please take out whatever is in the box called summation, add `int(number)` to it, and put it back in the box. But you haven't yet put anything in the box. So python says sorry, there's nothing in the box at the moment so I can't take anything out. Same for `new_list.append(a)`, that asks python to please append `a` to whatever is in the box. So python looks in the box to figure out how to append something to it but it can't find anything so it shows an error.

You may ask, why doesn’t python just put 0 in the box? Well, python doesn't know that what you want in the box is an int. Maybe you wanted a fraction, a complex number, or something you make up yourself that happens to be able to be added to a number. The same goes for the list, python does not know that you wanted a list and not a set, dictionary, tuple, counter, queue, or some other collection. So rather than guess, and possibly get it wrong (which would cause all kinds of weird bugs due to the slight differences in how these work with addition), it just gives you an error.

Comment: Actually, `new_list.append(a)` asks python to add `a` to the list described by the box.  Nothing is taken out of the box or put back.  If the box is not yet initialized, when python is asked to add `a` to the list described by the box, it will say "what list?  the box holds no such description".

Comment: @Steve Yea, it technically doesn't store it back in the box. It loads the thing in the box onto the stack, loads the append method, loads whatever is in `a`, calls the append method that it loaded, then ignores the result. I'll try to revise my answer to be a bit more clear. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: cool.  I really like your answer.  I was just throwing out a suggestion for a bit of improvement.  I hope it wasn't taken to be more than that.  The change you made is great!

Comment: @Steve I'm pretty new to actually answering questions rather than just reading them so I am always happy to have constructive criticism. I definitely think that I was able to make an improvement with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing with the variable. If you're assigning a value to the variable, it will initialize the variable in the loop itself. But if you want to modify a variable like you did with `.append()`, you have to declare it first as it has to be declared to be modified.